# How to call Javascript countdown after a day and add a week into the timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval

So I got a countdown and I just want when it ends to display a message ( it already does actually ) and wait 1 day, then start the countdown again with a week added into it.

That's the code :

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 17, 2018 20:00:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

var now = new Date().getTime();

var distance = countDownDate - now;

var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

if (days<1)
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ";
    if(hours<1)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ";
    }
    if(minutes<1)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = seconds + " Seconds ";}
    }
else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " Days " + hours + " Hours "
    + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ";
    }

if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Rewards are given!";
}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Well, You can bind the an infinite loop with timer, what is wrong ?

Comment: I don't know how to make the code wait for a day and then start the same function again.